# Error con ng build --prod en angular 5

Tags: angular4, angular-cli

Hola tengo un problema con angular 5, tengo una semana buscando respuestas a esto y me vi obligado a formular una pregunta aquí, mi problema es que cuando hago ng build --prod osea compilar el proyecto para producción me sale el error que aparece en la image pero cuando hago ng build o ng build --watch no me ningún y todo esta perfectamente tienen alguna idea de como resolver esto por favor necesito su ayuda   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías subir el código que se menciona en el error?

Comment: aqui esta todo el app.module.ts https://gist.github.com/crix07/45d746a6ca05c55a8e5f99faa2173b32